# How is this code giving me 0 as value of i, instead of 20?

Tags: java

I was excepting the value of i: 20, but it is giving me the value 0, Why I am getting value 0 in java 1.7 version?

```
public class InvalidValue {
    private int i = giveMeJ();
    private int j = 20;

    private int giveMeJ() {
        return j;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("i: " + new InvalidValue().i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried declaring `j` before declaring `i`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java keeps the default constructor if no constructor is present, Hence let us keep the default constructor in the code to understand the code flow and value of i and j at each step:

See Below code:

```
package com.java;

public class InvalidValue {
    private int i = giveMeJ();
    private int j = 20;

    // Default Constructor
    public InvalidValue() {
        super();
        // Second Print: inside Constructor[i= 0, j= 20]
        System.out.println("inside Constructor[i= " + i + ", j= " + j + "]");
    }

    private int giveMeJ() {
        // First Print: inside giveMeJ[i= 0, j= 0]
        System.out.println("inside giveMeJ[i= " + i + ", j= " + j + "]");
        return j;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Third Print: i: 0
        System.out.println("i: " + new InvalidValue().i);
    }
}
```

1. **Step 1:** void main initiate the call by **new InvalidValue().i**,
2. **Step 2:** **i** and **j** will be initiated by default value **0** then **InvalidValue()** constructor will be invoked and then **super();** will be
   called,
3. **Step 3:** Now the constructor (assign value to instance attributes) invokes **private int i = giveMeJ()**,
4. **Step 4:** **giveMeJ()** method will be invoked and here value of **i** is **0** also value of **j** is **0**, hence this method will **return 0**,
5. **step 5:** **i** initialize by **0**, now flow will go to **private int j = 20**,
6. **step 6:** **20** value will be assigned to **j**,
7. **step 7:** now the compiler will return to constructor **(Step 3)** and then it will print **sysout** statement (**inside Constructor[i= 0, j=
   20]**),
8. **step 8:** now compiler will return to **void main()** **(Step 1)** and it will print **sysout** statement (**i: 0**)

Answer (score 8):

The instance variables are initialized in the order of appearance. Therefore `private int i = giveMeJ()` is executed before `j` is initialized to 20, and therefore `i` is assigned the default value of `j`, which is `0`.

Comment: Caveat: If you make `j` final, it will be assigned first, because `final` with literal assignment makes it a *constant*.

Answer (score 2):

`j` is initialized to 20 **after** being used. What happens here is `giveMeJ()` used to initialize `i` returns the default value for `j` (which is 0), and only then `j` is initialized to 20. If you flip the order `i` and `j` and defined you'd get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

`j`  is initialized after `i` (though it is present there), and has the value of `0` at the time you call `giveMeJ()`. Hence you get `0`.

If you change `j` to `static`, you will see that it returns 20, as then its value will be fixed before you call the method.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**
When you run your program.First thing to run is static methods, and final and static fields(member variables) and then program is read line by line.

So here is how your program is running- 
First main is called. 
Then first field of newly created object InvalidValue is called.
It calls the giveMeJ.Then giveMeJ is read and it returns the value of j.

*Here as you can observe from the flow of the program j is never initialized.*

**Work Around**
Either make j static or final or both or initialize j above i.